# How to show only one toast based on 3 different values boolean of flows

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have the following three methods in **UpdateUserInfoRepo** each one is responsible for updating one of user data, like username,email or image,

```
class UpdateUserInfoRepoImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth,
    private val firestore: FirebaseFirestore,
    private val firebaseStorage: FirebaseStorage
) : UpdateUserInfoRepo {


    override suspend fun updateUserName(userName: String): MutableSharedFlow<Resource<Boolean>> {

        val result = MutableStateFlow<Resource<Boolean>>(Resource.Ideal())

        result.value = Resource.Loading()

        firestore.collection("USERS")
            .document(firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid!!)
            .update("userName", userName)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                result.value = Resource.Success(true)

            }.addOnFailureListener {
                result.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())
            }

        return result

    }


    override suspend fun updateUserProfileImage(imageDataByteArray: ByteArray): MutableSharedFlow<Resource<Boolean>> {

        val result = MutableStateFlow<Resource<Boolean>>(Resource.Ideal())

        result.value = Resource.Loading()

        val storageReference = firebaseStorage.reference

        val reference =
            storageReference.child("users/${firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid}/profile_picture.jpg")

        val uploadTask = reference.putBytes(imageDataByteArray)

        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener {

            reference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { imageUri ->


                firestore.collection("USERS")
                    .document(firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid!!)
                    .update("profileImage", imageUri.toString())
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        result.value = Resource.Success(true)
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener {
                        result.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())
                    }


            }.addOnFailureListener {
                result.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())
            }


        }.addOnFailureListener {
            result.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())
        }

        return result


    }


    override suspend fun updateEmail(
        oldEmail: String?,
        newEmail: String,
        password: String?,
        idToken: String?
    ): Flow<Resource<Boolean>> {
        val result = MutableStateFlow<Resource<Boolean>>(Resource.Ideal())

        result.value = Resource.Loading()

        if (idToken != null) {

            val authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)

            firebaseAuth.currentUser?.reauthenticate(authCredential)
                ?.addOnSuccessListener {

                    firebaseAuth.currentUser?.updateEmail(newEmail)
                        ?.addOnSuccessListener {


                            firestore.collection("USERS")
                                .document(firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid!!)
                                .update("email", newEmail)
                                .addOnSuccessListener {
                                    result.value = Resource.Success(true)

                                }.addOnFailureListener {
                                    result.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())
                                }


                        }?.addOnFailureListener {
                            result.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())
                        }

                }?.addOnFailureListener {
                    result.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())

                }
        } else {
            val authCredential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(oldEmail!!, password!!)

            firebaseAuth.currentUser?.reauthenticate(authCredential)
                ?.addOnSuccessListener {
                    firebaseAuth.currentUser?.updateEmail(newEmail)
                        ?.addOnSuccessListener {
                            firestore.collection("USERS")
                                .document(firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid!!)
                                .update("email", newEmail)
                                .addOnSuccessListener {
                                    result.value = Resource.Success(true)

                                }.addOnFailureListener {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "updateEmail: ${it.message.toString()}")
                                    result.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())
                                }
                        }?.addOnFailureListener {
                            Log.d(TAG, "updateEmail: ${it.message.toString()}")
                            result.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())

                        }
                }?.addOnFailureListener {
                    result.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())
                }

        }
        return result
    }
}
```

this **ViewModel** part, I using `MutableSharedFlow` for the three values

```
@HiltViewModel
class UpdateUserInfoViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val updateUserNameUseCase: UpdateUserNameUseCase,
    private val updateUserEmailUseCase: UpdateUserEmailUseCase,
    private val uploadUserProfileImageUseCase: UploadUserProfileImageUseCase,

) : ViewModel() {


    private var _updateUserNameState = MutableSharedFlow<Resource<Boolean>>()
    val updateUserNameState = _updateUserNameState.asSharedFlow()

    private var _updateUserEmailState = MutableSharedFlow<Resource<Boolean>>()
    val updateUserEmailState = _updateUserEmailState.asSharedFlow()

    private var _updateUserProfileImageState = MutableStateFlow<Resource<Boolean>>(Resource.Ideal())
    val updateUserProfileImageState = _updateUserProfileImageState.asSharedFlow()



    fun updateUserName(userName: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            updateUserNameUseCase(userName).collect {
                _updateUserNameState.emit(it)
            }
        }
    }

    fun updateUserEmail(
        oldEmail: String?,
        newEmail: String, password: String?,
        idToken: String? = null
    ) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            updateUserEmailUseCase(oldEmail, newEmail, password, idToken).collect {
                _updateUserEmailState.emit(it)
            }
        }
    }

    fun updateUserProfileImage(imageDataByteArray: ByteArray) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            uploadUserProfileImageUseCase(imageDataByteArray).collect {
                _updateUserProfileImageState.emit(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I collect each one in my **UpdateInfoFragment** like this

**The Problem** is when the user updates the username it will show the toast, also if the user updates the email it will show the toast, also the same with the profile image, but If the user updates two things together  (e.g like username and image) or the three values it will show the three toasts one after the other I need the way to check if any value is updated or the two value or All three together to show only one toast like **"Data updated successfully"**

```
 lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                updateUserInfoViewModel.updateUserNameState.collect { response ->

                    when (response) {
                        is Resource.Loading -> {
                            loadingDialog.show()
                        }

                        is Resource.Success -> {
                            loadingDialog.cancel()
                            Toast.makeText(
                                requireContext(),
                                "username updated successfully",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                            mainActivityViewModel.getUserInfo()

                        }

                        is Resource.Error -> {
                            loadingDialog.cancel()
                            Log.e(TAG, "updateUserNameState: ${response.message.toString()}")
                        }

                        else -> {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {

                updateUserInfoViewModel.updateUserEmailState.collect { response ->

                    when (response) {
                        is Resource.Loading -> {
//                            loadingDialog.create()
                            loadingDialog.show()
                        }

                        is Resource.Success -> {
                            loadingDialog.cancel()
                            Toast.makeText(
                                requireContext(),
                                "Email updated successfully",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                            mainActivityViewModel.getUserInfo()

                        }

                        is Resource.Error -> {

                            loadingDialog.cancel()
                            Log.e(TAG, "updateUserNameState: ${response.message.toString()}")
                        }

                        else -> {
                            loadingDialog.cancel()
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {


                updateUserInfoViewModel.updateUserProfileImageState.collect { response ->

                    when (response) {
                        is Resource.Loading -> {
//                            loadingDialog.create()
                            loadingDialog.show()
                        }

                        is Resource.Success -> {

                            loadingDialog.cancel()
                            Toast.makeText(
                                requireContext(),
                                "Profile image updated successfully",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                            mainActivityViewModel.getUserInfo()
                        }

                        is Resource.Error -> {

                            loadingDialog.cancel()
                            Log.e(TAG, "updateUserNameState: ${response.message.toString()}")
                        }

                        else -> {}
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

**My Try:** I tried to use combine to collect all three values together but by using this way it also shows one toast only if the three values are success and true

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                combine(
                    updateUserInfoViewModel.updateUserNameState,
                    updateUserInfoViewModel.updateUserEmailState,
                    updateUserInfoViewModel.updateUserProfileImageState
                    
                ) { updateUserNameState, updateUserEmailState, updateUserProfileImageState ->
                    val userNameSuccess =
                        updateUserNameState is Resource.Success && updateUserNameState.data == true
                    val emailSuccess =
                        updateUserEmailState is Resource.Success && updateUserEmailState.data == true
                    val profileImageSuccess =
                        updateUserProfileImageState is Resource.Success && updateUserProfileImageState.data == true


                    // Update the allUpdatesSuccessful flag
                    allUpdatesSuccessful = userNameSuccess && emailSuccess && profileImageSuccess

                    // Show the combined toast if all updates were successful

//
                    allUpdatesSuccessful
                }.collect {
                    if (allUpdatesSuccessful) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireContext(),
                            "All data updated successfully",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: If it is parallel API calls then you can use `coroutineScope` and async API calls with await function.
Refer this: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/parallel-multiple-network-calls-using-kotlin-coroutines/](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/parallel-multiple-network-calls-using-kotlin-coroutines/)

Comment: Looking at `updateUserName()`, the logic doesn't make sense to me. It's a suspend function that finishes doing everything before it returns the Flow, so why return a flow at all, much less a hot flow? It will be impossible for that Ideal or Loading state to ever be seen. Also, not related to this issue, but you should use the `Task.await()` suspend function. You are already using coroutines, so no need to enter "callback hell".

Comment: Toasts are probably the wrong way to display this information. They are intended more for messages that are system-related or global. And once you start one, it's in flight and can't be stopped early. So the best you could really do here is debounce it. So `combine()` your three flows, then use the `debounce()` operator to cut down on the series of quick emissions you're getting. This will induce a slight delay, but probably not a big deal. A few ms debounce will take out the duplicated messages when you do multiple things almost at once.

Comment: If you switch to SnackBars, on the UI side your collector could check if there's already a SnackBar open and collapse the new info into it. Probably would still want to debounce it, but might not need as much.

Comment: @tenfour04 How can I collect error or success states if I edit the method `updateUserName()` and use `await()` without Stateflow? can you edit the method in new answer, also no problem I can switch to using `snackbar` if it is better than toast in this case

Comment: It doesn't really answer your question, so I pasted an example here: https://pastebin.com/xtujVc5v The benefits of using `await` would be much more apparent in your other two functions since they currently have nested listeners.

Comment: So I will edit the method to return `Resource<Boolean>` but how can I will deal with ViewModel? do you suggest to keep using `MutableSharedFlow` and emitting the value for this method as  `Resource<Boolean>`

Comment: @tenfour04 I did these edits on the ViewModel

https://pastebin.com/jdDPFhB4

Comment: the flaw is not in the flow, or for that matter you need to fix something in the flow, it is in the design of your code, when you update multiple things there should be one ```emit``` call to the flow with a descriptive message regarding what all have changed.

Answer (score 1):

> [Flow in documentation:](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow)
> A flow is a type that can emit multiple values sequentially, as opposed to suspend functions that return only a single value.

So, here 3 flows are created for the username, email, and picture; each of which is triggered **once** either with success or failure. So, we expect one response here from each flow; not a stream of responses or values. So, you just need a suspend function for each.

Each suspend function needs to be run in a separate coroutine so they run in parallel.

And as the Toast need to be produced based on the result of these suspend functions; then these functions have to return back deferred results; so `async/await` Coroutine builder could be potentially used.

But, `async/await` will not help in this case because you need to trigger that from the Firebase listener different callbacks and that would be a different thread than that of the `async/await`.

So, we'd need some more control over the continuation of the suspend functions and that would be through the Continuation to suspend and return result at some point.

Here, the code will differ a bit, the `Resource` class that will be returned as a result would be a sealed class like:

```
sealed class Resource {
    object Loading : Resource()
    object Ideal : Resource()
    object Success : Resource()
    class Error(var message: String) : Resource()
}
```

Then to utilize the continuation, we can use [`suspendCancellableCoroutine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html):

Here's an extension function to the `Firestore` that returns `Resource` result:

```
suspend fun FirebaseFirestore.updateUserName(userName: String): Resource =
    suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->

        firestore.collection("USERS")
            .document(firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid!!)
            .update("userName", userName)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                continuation.resume(Resource.Success)

            }.addOnFailureListener {
                continuation.resume(Resource.Error(it.message.toString()))
            }
    }
```

Similarly for the profile pic:

```
suspend fun  FirebaseFirestore.updateUserProfileImage(imageDataByteArray: ByteArray): Resource =
    suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->

        val storageReference = firebaseStorage.reference

        val reference =
            storageReference.child("users/${firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid}/profile_picture.jpg")

        val uploadTask = reference.putBytes(imageDataByteArray)

        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener {

            reference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { imageUri ->

                firestore.collection("USERS")
                    .document(firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid!!)
                    .update("profileImage", imageUri.toString())
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        continuation.resume(Resource.Success)
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener {
                        continuation.resume(Resource.Error(it.message.toString()))
                    }

            }.addOnFailureListener {
                continuation.resume(Resource.Error(it.message.toString()))
            }


        }.addOnFailureListener {
            continuation.resume(Resource.Error(it.message.toString()))
        }

    }
```

And you can do the same for the email address.

Then to collect the result and show the Toast:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {

    val value = Resource.Loading // update whatsoever progress on the UI

    viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
    
         // Asynchronous Execution to execute in parallel.
        val userNameCheck = async {
            firestore.updateUserName("USERNAME")
        }

        val emailCheck = async {
            firestore.updateEmail(...)
        }   
        
        val profilePicCheck = async {
            firestore.updateUserProfileImage(...)
        }           
    
        if (userNameCheck == Resource.Success &&
            emailCheck == Resource.Success && 
            profilePicCheck == Resource.Success) { 
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),  "All data updated successfully", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        } 
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

> one toast for the three different values which means, If the user
> update all three values (username, email, photo) or updates anyone of
> them for example (username is true and the others is false) then shows
> one toast

So, you'd use the same procedure above for the three API calls, but just change the way you collect the data to show a single Toast.

I'd just modify the sealed class to have `isSuccess()` method that returns true for successful API call:

```
sealed class Result {
    object Loading : Result()
    object Ideal : Result()
    object Success : Result()
    class Error(var message: String) : Result()

    fun isSuccess() = this == Success
}
```

Then to collect the result and show a single Toast at the fragment by awaiting all the 3 results using `awaitAll()`:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {

    val value = Resource.Loading // update whatsoever progress on the UI

    viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
    
         // Asynchronous Execution to execute in parallel.
        val userNameCheck = async {
            firestore.updateUserName("USERNAME")
        }

        val emailCheck = async {
            firestore.updateEmail(...)
        }   
        
        val profilePicCheck = async {
            firestore.updateUserProfileImage(...)
        }           
    
        // await all the values before showing the Toast
        awaitAll(userNameCheck, emailCheck, profilePicCheck)

        val isUserNameSuccess = userNameCheck.await().isSuccess()
        val isEmailSuccess = emailCheck.await().isSuccess()
        val isProfilePicSuccess = profilePicCheck.await().isSuccess()

        val message = if (isUserNameSuccess && isEmailSuccess && isProfilePicSuccess) "All data updated successfully"
                      else if (isUserNameSuccess.not() && isEmailSuccess.not() && isProfilePicSuccess.not()) "All data not updated"
                      else "username success? $isUserNameSuccess email success? $isEmailSuccess profile pic success? $isProfilePicSuccess"

        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't have a chance to fully test that out using firebase APIs, but it's been tested on test environment. Feel free to show us the outcomes on Firebase

Comment: But this method is like combine in flow, which means only one toast will appear when the three values is true,

Comment: @DrMido, I am missed now. don't you need a single Toast as said in the question title? .. Also that is what I got from the OP.. So, In which cases do you need the toasts to show up?

Comment: one toast for the three different values which means, If the user update all three values (username, email, photo) or updates anyone of them for example (username is true and the others is false) then shows one toast, I hope you got it

Comment: @DrMido I got it, Kind of different than your OP; anyways do you want to do the three requests synchronously or asynchronously?

Comment: I think async because each update method is run separately or according to the solution, what do you suggest?

Comment: @DrMido Just updated the answer, please have a look. Hopefully it's Ok now.